# Make the "Help" icon link to the Help Center

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, top-bar, help-center

This is just a tiny request to simply change the `href` attribute of the "Help" icon's link from "#" to "/help".

[image]

All the other icons/menus have useful links except for this one. So, I believe it should be changed for consistency and because those links are good for two situations:

1. If one wants to explicitly open them using right-click > Open in a new tab/window or using a middle-click, for example.
2. When the script to open the menus is not loaded for some reason (e.g., JavaScript disabled, poor connection, etc.).

Note that putting aside the consistency issue, that button is currently **useless** when JavaScript is disabled, which is the [main](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1043678) [reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/574094) for why the other buttons have fallback links.

Comment: I am seeing a menu that includes Help-Center as one of the options.

Comment: @WalterMitty The link href serves as a _fallback_ to the menu. All the other menu links have this fallback.

Comment: This makes perfect sense for consistency sake; the other 4 icons have fallback links (Inbox links to [global Stack inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox), Trophy links to [global rep graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation), Review links to [site's review page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review), and the Stack Exchange button links to the [global home page](https://stackexchange.com/)), the help button should too!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A fix for this has now been released network-wide. As a fallback, the Help icon in the top bar now links directly to /help.

Thanks again for reporting!

Comment: Thanks for the fix and welcome to Meta :)

Comment: Happy to help out! Sorry it took so long to get to.

Comment: @Tyler most feature requests wait long years, so less than a year is really super fast. :)